# How to configure Beyond Compare 3 for Eclipse conflict resolution?

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff, conflict, beyondcompare

What is the correct parameters to get Beyond Compare 3 working with Eclipse/Subclipse conflict resolution?

In `Preferences > Team > SVN > Diff/Merge` there's the option to specify an external program to resolve conflicts.

The default parameters are:

```
"${yours}" "${theirs}" "${base}" "${merged}"
```

And it suggests TortoiseMerge settings of this:

```
/theirs:"${theirs}" /base:"${base}" /mine:"${yours}" /merged:"${merged}"
```

But what is the appropriate config for Beyond Compare?

Comment: +1 for using BC3 in the first place.  Awesome stuff.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to include it then in a merge operation of Subversive? I have tried your parameters, but could not find the right menu entry to start BC3.

Comment: This answer gave me what I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7749442/289770

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is correct:

```
"${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}"
```

Based on this forum post:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=368#4

To label the sections appropriately, and run BC in a separate (solo) instance, it's this:

```
"${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}"
/lefttitle="Incoming (${theirs})"
/centertitle="Base (${base})"
/righttitle="Local (${yours})"
/outputtitle="Merged (${merged})"
/solo
```

*Multiple lines used above for readability, replace linebreaks with spaces for use, i.e.*

```
 "${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}" /lefttitle="Incoming (${theirs})" /centertitle="Base (${base})" /righttitle="Local (${yours})" /outputtitle="Merged (${merged})" /solo
```

Comment: I try your solution, and remove the linebreaks to make it in one line, but it also cannot work. Any mistake?

Comment: None that I'm aware of - I set this up again a little back and it appeared to work.  You do need to replace linebreaks with spaces rather than just remove them though - did you do that?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have replace linebreaks with spaces, but it still cannot work. The code is `"${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}" /lefttitle="Incoming (${theirs})" /centertitle="Base (${base})" /righttitle="Local (${yours})" /outputtitle="Merged (${merged})" /solo`

Comment: Hmmm, dunno then. Probably worth double-checking on the [Scooter Software forums](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/) in case anything has changed?

Answer (score 4):

Also check out http://beyondcvs.sourceforge.net/ for an eclipse/Beyond Compare plugin. (from: http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs)

Comment: This is nice, but they lack the option to "compare with base from working copy", which is probably the most basic and frequently used comparison when working with SVN. Besides, it doesn't replace the default "compare" commands, but rather adds its own commands. I'll stick with manual configuration.

Comment: @YodanTauber have you verified that the plugin doesn't do what you want? It's been a long time since I've used svn, eclipse, or Beyond Compare, but I'm wondering if Compare With -> Local History doesn't compare the working copy with the base revision.

Comment: I used the latest version of BeyondCVS, and it didn't have that feature (though it has been suggested: http://sourceforge.net/p/beyondcvs/feature-requests/10/ ). Compare with Local History is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

AnkhSVN uses

For 3-way diff:

```
"$(ProgramFiles)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe" "$(Mine)" "$(Theirs)" "$(Base)" "$(Merged)" /title1="$(MineName)" /title2="$(TheirsName)" /title3="$(BaseName)" /title4="$(MergedName)"
```

Or for 2-way:

```
"$(ProgramFiles)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe" "$(Mine)" "$(Theirs)" /mergeoutput="$(Merged)" /title1="$(MineName)" /title2="$(TheirsName)"
```

You can probably tweak this to Subclipse's format.