# To view svn diff result in Notepad++/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff, notepad++

I run svn diff and have the content diff result in a text file.
Since the operation is slow I don't want to diff again using Eclipse.

I need to view the result in a better manner for comparison, and what I found is Colordiff.
I would like to ask are there any plugins in Notepad++ for the same purpose,
or are there any plugins in Eclipse to view the diff result with formatting?

(The scenario is I am on a branch which has some core changes and some global replacement. I need to compare this branch with the original.
With the help of a script, I filter out some of the global replacement, but still there are too many to check without help from tools.)

Comment: Before I give an answer, could you please explain what "to view the diff result with formatting" means? Do you expect something colorful, where should the diff be formatted and how?

Comment: yes, like using Colordiff I can load the diff txt result in linux, showing sth colorful

or anything similar to eclipse svn compare that can highlight the change, showing one on left and one or right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Eclipse, you should setup it with an Eclipse plugin for Subversion like Subversive or Subclipse. Both don't color the diff nicely, so if that is the main point, you should add an external diff tool to the definition (here for Subversive):

- Open `Window > Preferences > Team > SVN > Diff Viewer`
  [image]
- Define a new diff entry [image]

See the similar answer to a question I have asked in the past about intergration of a merge tool into Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749442/41540

Answer (score 2):

You can run `git diff ... > foo.diff` and open foo.diff in N++. This gives you a similar output like `git diff --color` in the shell. When you want to have a side-by-side view, you need to [set up an external diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff).

Comment: thanks for answer. seems git has a better support on this but unfortunately I am having a svn repo

Comment: @user891055 Sorry, I somehow mixed svn with git yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you're using any specific GUI tool for your used SCM? In case you're using TortoiseSVN or similar, then here's an approach for you to show diffs inside of Notepad++:

[How to use Notepad++ as diff viewer for TortoiseSVN (and similar tools).](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppCompareLoader.v0.1.zip)